# Testing a Facebook Group App with the new permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before the data breach at Facebook I had an app that was approved for the `user_managed_groups` permission. When they changed things my app became useless due to the restrictions on getting the user data from the comments.

I'm seeing now that Facebook has updated the API to allow apps to get that data provided each user of the group provides consent via graph login. I can easily add this to my workflow and provide the group admin a link for their users to consent.

The issue I am facing now is that the group admin must install the app into the group (see [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/261149227954100?helpref=popular_topics) help article for how this is accomplished), but apps cannot be installed unless they are approved by Facebook. This workflow seems like a catch 22: I can't test unless the app is installed but the app can't be installed unless it's approved.

How do I test my app if it can't be installed to the groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it with a group your app admin is an admin of, and a comment also made by that app admin user, that seems to work for me, according to a quick test in Graph API Explorer. (Comments made by other people with a role in the app probably work, too.)

The app must be in dev mode though, in live mode you will just get the error message saying the app must be installed in the group. If your app is currently in live mode and you can’t set it to dev mode, because you have other features that are in production already, then create a test app version of your app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps